# is possible to deduce a formula for vaccination coverage from Whittle threshold theorem?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am reading the article [Application of Whittle’s stochastic threshold theorem to a chickenpox outbreak](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/rsp/v40n4/15.pdf) and I can't understand the meaning of the term "intensity" in the Whittle threshold theorem.

In addition, they deduce a formula from Whittle's theorem for vaccination: $$p=1-\frac{1}{(1-\epsilon)^{1/a}R_0},$$ but I can't understand where it comes from and what the tolerance $\epsilon$ means.

I really appreciate your help.